# /bin/script and redirecting stderr

Tags: bash

I am using /bin/script to capture the output of a command and preserve the colors and formatting.  Using subshell and assigning to variable does not always work well.  E.g.,:

```
foo="$( ls --color 2>&1 )"
```

I can use /bin/script to capture stdout:

```
$ script -qc "echo foo" >& /dev/null && cat typescript
Script started on Mon 06 Nov 2017 10:40:40 PM PST
foo
```

I can use /bin/script to capture stderr (ls of non-existent directory goes to stderr):

```
$ script -qc "ls vxzcvcxvc" >& /dev/null && cat typescript
Script started on Mon 06 Nov 2017 10:38:17 PM PST
ls: cannot access vxzcvcxvc: No such file or directory
```

My problem arises when the script run inside /bin/script mucks with file descriptors.

I am not able to use /bin/script to capture redirected stderr:

```
$ script -qc "ls vxzcvcxvc 2>&1" >& /dev/null && cat typescript
Script started on Mon 06 Nov 2017 10:47:13 PM PST
```

I have tried other ways as well:

```
$ script -qc "echo foo1 && >&2 echo foo2 && echo foo3" >& /dev/null && cat typescript
Script started on Mon 06 Nov 2017 10:46:09 PM PST
foo1
foo3
```

I assume /bin/script is doing its own file descriptor magic (redirecting output to file), so I am left wondering what to do if the script I am calling does its own redirection.

Tangential question: The primary culprit is a logging line that does

```
printf "${1}" 1>&2
```

in order to print logging to stderr.  Is there a way to output to stderr without mucking with file descriptors (assuming this is the reason /bin/script fails to pick it up)?

Comment: `printf "$@"` is innately buggy, unless `$1` is a format string and `$2` and forward are values to be substituted into it.

Comment: BTW, your example does not, in and of itself, substantiate the claim that "using a subshell and assigning to a variable does not always work well". That command substitution certainly *does* store the entire output of `ls` to your variable -- I wonder if perhaps it's later being emitted in a manner that drops content (ie. if you were testing with `echo $foo` instead of `echo "$foo"` or `printf '%s\n' "$foo"`)?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with the commands given. Please copy-paste your examples from this post into your terminal and verify that you get the result you post.

Comment: And `printf ...anything... 2>&1` doesn't print to stderr *at all*; it's explicitly and exclusively writing contents only to stdout.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 1) Fixed typo for printf 2>&1  2) I do not care about printf being 'buggy' without a format string.  It is as equally buggy as echo and bash as long as we are generalizing. 3) You are right, my example does not "in and of itself" prove my problem associated with subshells.  Simple redirects like that work without issue; more complex ones do not.  That is an exercise left to reader.  If you are still hung up on it, consider how you would store 500kb of terminal output in a shell variable for later use

Comment: Try running `printf "one" "two" "three"`. It doesn't do anything that could *remotely* be considered correct or desirable behavior. So I entirely, wholeheartedly disagree with the "equally buggy as echo" -- `printf` is much more reliable when used correctly, but "used correctly" *absolutely requires an explicit format string*.

Comment: and `var=$(generate-500kb-of-data)` works fine (so long as your data doesn't contain any NUL literals), so I still don't know what you're trying to convey above.

Comment: @thatotherguy Good news!  What shell / version are you using?

Comment: Changing from `$@` to `$1` is a start. `printf '%b' "$1"` -- as suggested in the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- would go further (assuming processing escape sequences rather than emitting them exactly as they were received is actually desired behavior -- if your content was captured with `output=$(command)`, I don't know why it would be; I would expect `printf '%s\n' "$1"` to be correct in that case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I changed printf again to satisfy your pedantry.  I appreciate you pointing out the flaws in my simplifications, but let there be no doubt that you are wasting my time.  I appreciate you might be trying to help find an underlying issue, but I do not have time to explain it all.  If you know nothing of /bin/script, simply move on.

Comment: I *know of* `script`. I also strongly prefer to avoid its needless use and advise others to do likewise. Thus, I'm trying to determine if your issue can be nailed down such that I actually understand what you're trying to do and what issues are inhibiting that, such that a `script`-free solution can be built.

Comment: @Dave This is with GNU bash 4.4.12 with script from util-linux 2.30.2

Comment: @thatotherguy I started a CentOS VM and it works!  Unfortunately, am working on older RHEL.  One of the boxes has util-linux-ng, which according to wikipedia was folded back into util-linux back in 2011.  The other box is slightly newer, but apparently not that much.  Both RHEL boxes behave differently than the CentOS box.  Need to upgrade (and learn python finally)